# The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<SingleChildWidget>'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, bloc, type-mismatch

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: AppPages.allBlocProviders(context) ,
      child: ScreenUtilInit(
      builder: (context, child) =\>  MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: const Welcome(),
          theme: ThemeData(
            appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                color: AppColors.primaryText
              ),
              elevation: 0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white
            )
          ),
          onGenerateRoute: AppPages.GenerateRouteSettings,
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

This is main dart file cause the error

```
class PageEntity{
  String route;
  Widget page;
  dynamic bloc;

  PageEntity({required this.route, required this.page,  this.bloc});
}
```

This is entity class that help to iterate through the providers

```
class AppPages{

  static List<PageEntity> routes (){
    return [
      PageEntity(
      route: AppRoutes.INITIAL, 
      page: const Welcome(), 
      bloc: BlocProvider(create: (_)=>WelcomeBloc(),)
    ),
      PageEntity(
      route: AppRoutes.SING_IN, 
      page: const SignInPage(), 
      bloc: BlocProvider(create: (_)=>SignInBlocs(),)
    ),
      PageEntity(
      route: AppRoutes.REGISTER, 
      page: const Register(), 
      bloc: BlocProvider(create: (_)=>RegisterBlocs(),)
    ),
      PageEntity(
      route: AppRoutes.APPLICATION, 
      page: const Welcome(), 
    ),
    ];
  }


// return all the bloc providers
   static List<dynamic> allBlocProviders(BuildContext context){
    List<dynamic> blocProviders = <dynamic>[];
    for(var bloc in routes()){
    
        blocProviders.add(bloc.bloc);
      
    }
    return blocProviders;
  }class AppPages{

  static List<PageEntity> routes (){
    return [
      PageEntity(
      route: AppRoutes.INITIAL, 
      page: const Welcome(), 
      bloc: BlocProvider(create: (_)=>WelcomeBloc(),)
    ),
      PageEntity(
      route: AppRoutes.SING_IN, 
      page: const SignInPage(), 
      bloc: BlocProvider(create: (_)=>SignInBlocs(),)
    ),
      PageEntity(
      route: AppRoutes.REGISTER, 
      page: const Register(), 
      bloc: BlocProvider(create: (_)=>RegisterBlocs(),)
    ),
      PageEntity(
      route: AppRoutes.APPLICATION, 
      page: const Welcome(), 
    ),
    ];
  }


// return all the bloc providers
   static List<dynamic> allBlocProviders(BuildContext context){
    List<dynamic> blocProviders = <dynamic>[];
    for(var bloc in routes()){
    
        blocProviders.add(bloc.bloc);
      
    }
    return blocProviders;
  }
}
```

This is where all the providers lies

what I tried:

I tried to change the return type dynamic to `BlocProvider`.

I changed the providers property to

```
AppPages.allBlocProviders(context) to  [...AppPages.allBlocProviders(context)].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `dynamic` in the `allBlocProviders` function so all three places you have written `dynamic` you should put `BlocProvider` and also check if the bloc isn't null, like

```
static List<BlocProvider> allBlocProviders(BuildContext context){
  List<BlocProvider> blocProviders = <BlocProvider>[];
  for (var bloc in routes()){
    if (bloc.bloc != null) {
      blocProviders.add(bloc.bloc!);
    }
  }
  return blocProviders;
}
```

and also in the `PageEntity` change

```
dynamic bloc;
```

to

```
BlocProvider? bloc;
```