# Could not find the correct Provider<WelcomeBloc> above this BlocBuilder<WelcomeBloc, WelcomeState> Widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, exception, bloc

I solved the error type mismatching from this but now another exception was thrown

[The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<SingleChildWidget>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77492698/the-argument-type-listdynamic-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-list)

This is the console output

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Welcome(state: _WelcomeState#276b6):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this BlocBuilder<WelcomeBloc, WelcomeState> Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that BlocBuilder<WelcomeBloc, WelcomeState> is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
  ```

The relevant error-causing widget was

Welcome pages.dart:19

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack.

This is my main.dart file after modify this

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: AppPages.allBlocProviders(context) ,
      child: ScreenUtilInit(
      builder: (context, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: ThemeData(
              appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
                iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                  color: AppColors.primaryText
                ),
                elevation: 0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white
              )
            ),
            onGenerateRoute: AppPages.GenerateRouteSettings,
          );
        },
      )
    );
  }
```

This is my welcome.dart file.

```
    return  BlocBuilder<WelcomeBloc, WelcomeState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 34.h),
              width: 375.w,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                children: [
                  PageView(
                    controller: pageController,
                    onPageChanged: (value) {
                      state.page = value;
                      BlocProvider.of<WelcomeBloc>(context).add(WelcomeEvent());
                      // print(value);
                    },
                    children: [
                      _page(
                        1,
                        context,
                        "Next",
                        "First See Learning",
                        "Forget about a for of paper all knowledge in on learning",
                        "assets/images/reading.png"
                      ),
                      _page(
                        2,
                        context,
                        "Next",
                        "Connect With Everyone",
                        "Always keep in touch with your tutor & friend, Let's get connected",
                        "assets/images/boy.png"
                      ),
                      _page(
                        3,
                        context,
                        "Get Started",
                        "Always Fascinated Learning",
                        "Anywhere, anytime, The time is at our direction so study whenever you want",
                        "assets/images/man.png"
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 100.h,
                    child: DotsIndicator(
                      position: state.page,
                      dotsCount: 3,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      decorator: DotsDecorator(
                        color: AppColors.primaryThirdElementText,
                        activeColor: AppColors.primaryElement,
                        size: const Size.square(8.0),
                        activeSize: const Size(18.0, 8.0),
                        activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
                        )
                      ),
                    )
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

This is my modified pages.dart file

```
  static List<PageEntity> routes (){
    return [
      PageEntity(
      route: AppRoutes.INITIAL, 
      page: const Welcome(), 
      bloc: BlocProvider(create: (context)=>WelcomeBloc(),)
    ),
      PageEntity(
      route: AppRoutes.SING_IN, 
      page: const SignInPage(), 
      bloc: BlocProvider(create: (context)=>SignInBlocs(),)
    ),
      PageEntity(
      route: AppRoutes.REGISTER, 
      page: const Register(), 
      bloc: BlocProvider(create: (context)=>RegisterBlocs(),)
    ),
    ];
  }


// return all the bloc providers
   static List<BlocProvider> allBlocProviders(BuildContext context){
    List<BlocProvider> blocProviders = <BlocProvider>[];
    for(var blocs in routes()){
      if(blocs.bloc != null){
        blocProviders.add(blocs.bloc!);
      }
    }
    return blocProviders;
  }


  // model that cover entire screen as we click on navigator object
  static MaterialPageRoute GenerateRouteSettings(RouteSettings settings){
    if(settings.name !=null){
      // check for route name matching when navigator gets triggered.
      var result = routes().where((element) => element.route == settings.name);
      if(result.isNotEmpty){
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> result.first.page, settings: settings);
      }
    }
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> const SignInPage(), settings: settings);
  }
}


class PageEntity{
  String route;
  Widget page;
  BlocProvider? bloc;

  PageEntity({required this.route, required this.page,  this.bloc});
}
```

How to I handle this error. I tired but can't find the solution.

Comment: The error message you posted tells you all you need to know. You are using a `BlocBuilder<WelcomeBloc>`, but there is no corresponding Provider above the Welcome widget. Try refactoring your PageEntity to use a `BlocProvider<WelcomeBloc>()`